# How to integrate Atom payment gateway to android app

Tags: android, payment-gateway, android-sdk-tools

I wanna integrate Atom payment gateway in my android app. But I'm getting an issue when trying to add the PayActivity class in my project. I've added this line "import com.atom.library_mobilepaymentsdk.*;" to my activity. But it still can not find the PayActiviyt class. In which I suppose to send all details of payments.

[image: MainActivity class]

[image: libraryMobilePaymentSdk build.gradle file]

[image: App build.gradle file]

Comment: please dont post images in your question for questions seeking debugging or code related help like these, it makes it very hard for others to copy paste it into their ide's

Comment: Hey, We are also facing same issue. Did you find any solution for this.

Comment: @sandeepmaaram yes I solved this problem. In generated build.gradle file of atom replace compile with api